# Not able to draw smooth lines in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, line

I am trying to make a small 2d game but when I try to make lines using the `LineRenderer` it is giving very jaggy lines.

I tried messing with settings in the `Camera` but sadly nothing worked.

I am using unity `2018.3.6f1`

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1539243/anti-aliasing-not-working-in-unity-20182-editor.html) might help you.

Comment: Could you first of all please set the **`Scale`** in the Game View to **`1`** instead of `1.25` and see if the issue is gone? In other words: Never zoom on the Game view .. causes all kind of shits ^^

Comment: @derHugo your solution solved the problem, thank you so much